# Python getopt not setting correct value

Tags: python, getopt

*It could be I'm completely misunderstanding the getopt module*

I am trying to parse [--magic-m] to my program, but it does not set the correct field.

**Part of Encrypt Function**

```
def encrypt(filename, text, magic):
    if not magic is None:
        hash = pbkdf2_sha256.encrypt(magic, rounds=10000, salt_size=16)
        print pbkdf2_sha256.verify(magic, hash)
    try:
        d = load_image( filename )
    except Exception,e:
        print str(e)
```

**Part of Load function**

```
def load_image( filename ) :
    img = Image.open( os.path.join(__location__, filename) )
    img.load()
    data = np.asarray( img, dtype="int32" )
    return data
```

**Main**

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not len(sys.argv[1:]):
        usage()
    try:
        opts,args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],"hedm:",["help", "encrypt", "decrypt", "magic="])
    except getopt.GetoptError as err:
        print str(err)
        usage()

    magic = None
    for o,a in opts:
        if o in ("-h","--help"):
            usage()
        elif o in ("-e","--encrypt"):
            to_encrypt = True
        elif o in ("-d","--decrypt"):
            to_encrypt = False
        elif o in ("-m", "--magic"):
            magic = a
        else:
            assert False,"Unhandled Option"

    print magic
    if not to_encrypt:
        filename    = sys.argv[2]
        decrypt(filename, magic)
    else:
        filename    = sys.argv[2]
        text        = sys.argv[3]
        encrypt(filename, text, magic)
```

I tried calling the program above like this:

```
[1] python stego.py -e test.jpeg lol -m h
```

or like this:

```
[2] python stego.py -e -m h test.jpeg lol
```

Output becomes:

```
[1] None

[2] lol
[2] True
[2] [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Educontract\\Steganography\\-m'
```

**Whitout the option -m everything works fine**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The colon should come *after* `m` to indicate that it requires an argument. You should also include an equals sign after the long option `magic` to indicate that it requires an argument.

```
getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:],"hedm:",["help", "encrypt", "decrypt", "magic="])
```

You should put all your options *before* the arguments, as in your second example.

```
python stego.py -e -m h test.jpeg lol
```

If you print `sys.argv`, I think you'll find that `sys.argv[2]` and `sys.argv[3]` are not what you expect. I would fetch the arguments from `args`, rather than `sys.argv`.

```
filename    = args[0]
text        = args[1]
```

Note that you may find it easier to use the [`argparse`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html) library instead of `getopt`. It isn't as strict about requiring options before arguments.

Comment: I tried this but it still gives me an error`C:\Users\Educontract\Steganography>python stego.py -e -m lol test.jpeg lol` gives `lol True [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Educontract\\Steganography\\-m'`

Comment: I will lookup argparse to see if it is more suitable for my needs

Comment: @Ludisposed which error? note that you have put the colon _before_ the "magic" argument.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I alterted that line to what Alasdair suggested

Comment: Please edit your question and include the full traceback.

Comment: @Alasdair I did, as Traceback was already in question. I think I am mucking things up when I try to parse the rest of the arguments to the program. Because it tries to open with `-m` thus `sys.argv[2] = -m`?

Comment: That doesn't look like the full traceback. It's not clear where `No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Educontract\\Steganography\\-m'` is coming from.

Comment: Edited, it tries to load a file with the filename I set at `sys.argv[2]`

Comment: @Alasdair Perfect! Should read some more about `sys.argv` and `args` But thank you for clearing this up for me!